# Why my button is not clickable when I dismissed the modal dialog in Ionic app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to retrieve the values from an Ionic modal. Anytime I exit the modal and go back to the previous page which is the main page, the button on that page no longer remain clickable.

How do I prevent this from happening?
PS: I have used modals for both alert and data retrieval from pop-ups.

I have tried using following approach:

```
myModal.onDidDismiss((data)=>{
    this.token=data.token;
    this.newpin = data.pin;
}};
return await myModal.present();
```

What I am expecting is I want my modal to work as expected without breaking the buttons on my previous page. Please advise.

Comment: Are you Angular or AngularJs.

Comment: I guess it's ionic 2+ because the modal api matches with that.

Comment: well.. my ionic version is  ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2. is there a better approach to solving this.